# No module 'pandas_gbq'

Tags: python, pandas, pip

Hi I need a solution how to add this module.I get an error while running some code :
import pandas_gbq
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_gbq'

I try use: pip install pandas-gbq ( but it doesn't work)

Comment: did you try: `pip install pandas-gbq -U`? do you have pip installed?

Comment: pip install should work - https://pypi.org/project/pandas-gbq/

Comment: pip was installed because I add some modules before, I try this also but It doesn't work

Comment: when installing using pip3 it is`Successfully installed pandas-gbq-0.17.1` but while importing I get the same error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_gbq'`

Answer (score 1):

you can install with  git

```
 pip install git+https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery-pandas.git
```

or

```
pip install pandas-gbq -U
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using,

```
from pandas.io import gbq
```

If the above solution doesn't work and you are getting Certificate Fail related error use the code below and it will solve the issue,

```
pip config set global.trusted-host "pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org pypi.python.org"
```